# Function call inside another function is not getting evaluated [JMeter]

Tags: jmeter

I am using function call inside another function in **JSR223 Pre Processor**

1. Getting the Request Body from Parent HTTP Sampler

   ```
   String requestBody = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
   log.info("Request body is : " + requestBody);
   ```
2. Value getting processed properly in __V function

   ```
   log.info(${__V(requestBody)});
   ```
3. Same __V function is not getting evaluated inside MD5 function

   ```
   String md5hash = "${__MD5(${__V(requestBody)},)}";
   log.info("md5hash is : " + md5hash);
   ```
4. JMeter log is given below:

   ```
   2022-03-17 15:10:01,135 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor: Request body is : {
       "contact":"1234567890"
   }
   2022-03-17 15:10:01,135 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor: {
       "contact":"1234567890"
   }
   2022-03-17 15:10:01,135 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor: md5hash is : 
   1be38aa366c4b7daef5e4b527902a97b
   ```

The MD5 hash generated at step 4 i.e. **1be38aa366c4b7daef5e4b527902a97b** is of **requestBody** text. I want MD5 to be generated for **requestBody** variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in Groovy scripts, as per JSR223 Sampler Documentation:

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance.
>
> When using this feature, **ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement**. Instead use script parameters.

In order to generate MD5 checksum of the `requestBody` variable use the following code:

```
def md5hash = vars.get('requestBody').md5()
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Hi @Dmitri, the above function does not return correct MD5 value, for e.g. my request body is {
    "contact":"9876543210"
}. The correct MD5 hash value is a73602753fe29e781aebc24a14d6e203, but the md5 function returns value as 904c7a176f07435919ac6a7a08662166

Comment: This function does return correct md5 checksum for the `requestBody` variable value, if the checksum is different from what you expect you need to re-visit the place where you create/assign this variable. Its value can be checked using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

Comment: I am now not using the Functions inside JSR223 Sampler, but instead using the .md5() function.